как выполнять дальнейший асинхронный код только в случае если определённое exe приложение запущено ? python
Как выполнять дальнейший асинхронный код,
только в случае если определённое exe приложение запущено ?
Есть асинхронный код взаимодействующий с exe приложением,
как ожидать открытия приложения в случае если оно закрыто,
и продолжать в случае если оно открыто.
Хотелось бы использовать для этого функцию возвращающую true/false

В цикле проверять, запущено ли приложение, делать небольшую паузу (допустим, await asyncio.sleep(0.5)), проверять еще раз.

@insolor каким образом реализовать проверку запуска приложения ?

Смотря что за приложение. Если оконное - искать по заголовку или классу окна. Если не оконное - по списку процессов искать нужный процесс по имени.

Вот небольшой пример:
import win32gui
import pygetwindow as gw


def get_all_windows():
    """Возвращает словарь, содержащий заголовки окон и их дескрипторы (hwnd)."""
    def _MyCallback(hwnd, extra):
        hwnds, classes = extra
        hwnds.append(hwnd)
        classes[win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)] = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)

    windows = []
    classes = {}
    win32gui.EnumWindows(_MyCallback, (windows, classes))
    return classes

print("Список всех открытых окон:")
for key, value in get_all_windows().items():
    if key != "":
        print("\t* " + key.split("\n")[0])
        print(value)

    else:
        print("\t* " + key.split("\n")[0])
        print(value)

for title in gw.getAllTitles():
    print(title)

Дальше, думаю разберётесь. Успехов!
